# Different ways of loading DLL into MFC?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

What are the different ways to load a win32 or MFC DLL into an MFC application?

I know there are 2 ways to link a DLL. 1.) Include the lib file created with the DLL 2.) Using .def file and LoadLibrary function. Is there any other ways to link the DLL?

Regards,
AH

Answer (score 0):

This can be done dynamically or statically depending on your requirement.

This link gives you enough information.

http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/tutorials/article.php/c9855

Comment: Yes.
I know there are 2 ways to link a DLL.
1.) Include the lib file created with the DLL
2.) Using .def file and LoadLibrary function.

Is there any other ways to link the DLL?

Comment: What is wrong with the 2 ways that are present and what is your specific requirement.

Comment: Hey, Got it.
There are three ways of loading. Along with the two ways of loading DLL as i mentioned earlier, The third ways is using "AfxLoadLibrary" and "FreeLibrary". Please refer the link for further details.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/DLL/loadingdll.aspx

Answer (score 0):

No, there are no other ways. It's either static or dynamic. Also, you don't need a .def file for LoadLibrary.